# Using body parser limit

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Im using the body Parser like following and I provide a limit of 10Mb
my question is

How I can determine the real limit for example I can put 1000mb but it really use that?

```
app.use(bodyParser.raw({
    type: 'application/octet-stream',
    limit: '10mb'
}));
```

Comment: have you tried, it seems like any arbitrary number would work, but you probably don't want people uploading GB files

Comment: The true limit depends on a number of factors. For example, if your app is behind an nginx proxy, the limit is affected by the [client_max_body_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) parameter. If you’re behind an Apache proxy for some reason, the [LimitRequestBody](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive would affect this.